# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - подскажите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

В редакторе курса, который прохожу невозможно посмотреть что не так. Редактор OpenJSCAD. Написала код для фигуры - он отображается без ошибок и завернула его в функцию translate как по правилам в wiki в фигурные скобки, но отображается ошибка про скобку. Подскажите пожалуйста решение, я новичок.

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Line: 35,col: 531
(https://files.openedu.ru/compgr/lab-cg/index.html)

```
translate([3.5, 5, 4])
{
    CSG.cube({ 
        corner1: [0, 0, 0],  
        corner2: [7, 10, 8]
        }).subtract(
            CSG.cube({
                corner1: [0, 2, 3],  
                corner2: [7, 10, 8]
                }).setColor([ 
                255,
                255,
                0    
                ])
        ).subtract(
            CSG.cylinder({
                start: [3.5, 10, 0],  
                end: [3.5, 10, 3], 
                radius: 1.5, 
                resolution: 32 
                }).setColor([
                    255,
                    255,
                    0    
                    ]) 
        ).union(
            CSG.cylinder({  
                start: [3.5, 2, 5.5],  
                end: [3.5, 6.5, 5.5], 
                radius: 2, 
                resolution: 32
                })
            ).subtract(
                CSG.cylinder({
                    start: [3.5, 0, 5.5],  
                    end: [3.5, 6.5, 5.5], 
                    radius: 1.5, 
                    resolution: 32 
                    }).setColor([ 
                    255,
                    255,
                    0    
                    ]) 
                )
}
```

Comment: а `translate` - это че. класс ?)

Comment: тут у вас даже 2 ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translate, похоже, вызывается так:

```
translate(координаты, фигура)
```

В вашем случае будет так:

```
translate([3.5, 5, 4],
    CSG.cube({ corner1: [0, 0, 0], corner2: [7, 10, 8]})
        .subtract(CSG.cube({corner1: [0, 2, 3],corner2: [7, 10, 8]}).setColor([255,255,0]))
        .subtract(CSG.cylinder({start: [3.5, 10, 0],end: [3.5, 10, 3],radius: 1.5,resolution: 32}).setColor([255,255,0]))
        .union(CSG.cylinder({start: [3.5, 2, 5.5],end: [3.5, 6.5, 5.5],radius: 2,resolution: 32}))
        .subtract(CSG.cylinder({start: [3.5, 0, 5.5],end: [3.5, 6.5, 5.5],radius: 1.5,resolution: 32}).setColor([255,255,0])))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, в вики почему-то другие примеры. Не подскажите ещё, как к одной и той же фигуре применить несколько функций?